# top:1px calculated differently in chrome and FF

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I was just recently debugging a site **[SEE HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/salylimon-web/html/V1/)**, Now if you scroll to the section immediately after the banner , the section with the accodion.

[image]

As you can see from the above image that the active tab has a top arrow that faces upwards. the css code is as follows:

```
.hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li.active > a {
    font-weight: 900;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    background: url(../images/res/active-accordion-tab.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Notice how `postion:relative` and `top:1px` are used to cover the border that passes below, giving the impression that the active that has just an arrow and no bottom border. Now this works fine in chrome but in FF there is a small problem the 1px does't quite get the arrow down enough to cover the border and the arrow on the active tab looks like below:

[image]

See how the arrow does quite cover the bottom border. What is the solution to this ??

P.S. i can't used `top:2px` because then in chrome things look a bit bad.

Comment: maybe it's the image. try messing around with the zoom on the page and see if the problem fixes itself. When I tried this in Chrome, zooming in once (`ctrl++`) was enough to make the border show. You might need to scale the image a bit bigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this depends on OS-level and browser-level zoom. Looks like your font doesn’t actually have bold glyphs, so to apply `font-weight: bold`, browsers are forced to generate bold glyphs based on normal glyphs and do this *differently*.

Given that your menu items are `inline-block`s, you should add `vertical-align: bottom` to them for their bottom edge’s position to be unaffected by rasterization rounding errors and therefore predictable and consistent across browsers:

```css
.hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

By the way, I would recommend you to get rid of shifting the active link itself by `1px` to bottom (i.e. remove `position: relative; top: 1px;` from the active link’s styles), and use an absolutely-positioned CSS-generated pseudoelement instead:

```
.hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li.active > a {
    position: relative;
}

.hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li.active > a:after {
    background: url(active-accordion-tab.jpg) no-repeat;
    content: '';
    margin-left: -7px; /* Half the width to center the arrow. */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -1px; /* Compensating menu's border-bottom. */
    width: 14px;
    height: 8px;
}
```

Comment: I would opt for the pseudo element, too

Answer (score 2):

Change your `top:1px` to `top:1.5px` it works perfectly fine on both browsers i.e. `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

```
.hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li.active > a {
    font-weight: 900;
    position: relative;
    top: 1.5px;
    background: url(../images/res/active-accordion-tab.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Comment: i was more interested in WHY the 1px does't work in FF .

Comment: It's usually happens and it's mostly because of padding somewhere. Result differs in Chrome and Firefox, whereas Chrome and opera output are always same.

Comment: @frnt, that's because chrome and opera are both webkit browsers, whereas firefox is a gecko browser.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Well that could be the reason, but I have usually encountered this difference in chrome and firefox. But over-here for li vertical-align works fine.

Answer (score 1):

That is because it displays different different font size for different browser. There is minor difference.

To solve this:

Use:

```
.accordion-list-items > li.active {
    font-weight: 900;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And remove `font-weight: 900;` from `.hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li.active > a`

[Reference link:](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/)

> The font-weight property sets the weight, or thickness, of a font and is dependent either on available font faces within a font family or weights **defined by the browser**.
>
> If a font has a bold ("700") or normal ("400") version as part of the font family, the browser will use that. If those are not available, **the browser will mimic its own bold or normal version of the font**.

Answer (score 0):

you use display `inline-block`  you should add `vertical-align:top`

add `vertical-align: top;` this class

```
.hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li > a {
    color: #000;
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding-bottom: 1.25em;` from here

```
.hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li > a {
    color: #000;
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and add it here,

```
.hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li.active > a {
    font-weight: 900;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    background: url(../images/res/active-accordion-tab.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
   padding-bottom: 1.25em;
}
```

this should solve the padding problem and make it look the same in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 

    .hm-our-products-main-showcase .accordion-list-items > li {
      display: inline-block;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      vertical-align: top;
}
```

Give `vertical-align: top;` to your li element because you are using `display: inline-block;` while using `inline-block` we should align vertically to avoid this type of issues.